# Are there any cheap printing options for a small order?

Tags: printing

We plan to release our debut novel at the end of 2014. Unfortunately I do not have the funds to pay many of the costs involved to have the book printed en masse so I am going down the digital route for the first book. However it would be nice to have a few copies printed for family and friends to give as gifts. Is anybody aware of a company that doesn't charge 'through the nose' to have between 30-50 books printed?

Comment: Please check out other questions under the printing tag; you may find an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PODW http://www.printondemand-worldwide.com/ will give you an instant quote on it through their website, and that walks you through all of the choices you can make.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Lulu Press](http://www.lulu.com/shop/index-new.ep) in the past.  You can order one book at a time if you want from them.

And if you are willing to go ebook, then look at Amazon and Barnes & Noble too.

Wikipedia's [article on self-publishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-publishing) is a good general place to start searching.

Comment: Be careful of shipping costs at Lulu. A very small print run, or single copies, and shipping can easily chew up 30-50% of your costs.

Comment: Agree.  The main reasons to use Lulu, for me at least, were perfect binding and direct sales.  I could not get perfect binding at Kinkos or any other quick printing place I found.  I also like that Lulu gives me a URL I could share with others who could buy directly.

Comment: I love Lulu, and use it to print my books. And shipping's such a problem that it routinely costs me sales.